# Applying Stereotypes in Enterprise Architect does not add inherited tagged values

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have defined a new profile including a stereotype for the **UML::Activity** in enterprise architect. Let's call it "**MyActivity**". As I instantiate from MyActivity using **Toolbox**, the shape of the element and also the **Tagged Values** are displayed as I've defined. But when I instantiate from the base type (UML::Activity) and then apply the MyActivity stereotype to it, only the appearance of the element is updated to my definition. The tagged values that are defined in my stereotype will not be included/presented in the element.

Is it a bug in Enterprise Architect? or do I make mistake somewhere?
My EA version 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stereotypes have only been added automatically since EA 10.0. If you have an earlier version, you must right-click the stereotype in the toolbox and use the Synchronize command which will add the tagged values for all elements in the model with that stereotype. The alternative is to drag the stereotype from the toolbox and drop it onto an existing element.

Comment: Thanks! This solution completely resolved the problem.